# Trying to understand stored procedure behavior

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I'm tired of searching for this, but I couldn't find anything.

I have three databases in SQL Server and although all stored procedures are in the `Main` database, they work with tables from the other databases.

My question is: if you have the query

```
select name 
from SecondDatabase.dbo.SomeTable 
where id = 56
```

and this query is stored in the main database, will it run in the main database and go all the way to the second database and returns the data, or will it run in the second database and you have the select result directly?

(hope you understand my question)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. All three databases are on the same instance? Can you share some code and try to explain what your question is?

Comment: Hi Sean. Yes, it is on the same instance, but I'm trying to understand in a general context of how the engine behaves in this kind of environment. Try to imagine two partitioned databases , one the first you have all the stored procedures but you want to do a select on the second one.

Comment: The definition of *main* isn't clear here. It simply seems like you are executing a procedure which is on ServerA against ServerB. Is this question asking is this possible or how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, it was ony a way to call the databases. You can say that it as the first database and the second database

Comment: You can qualify the database schema and schema owner on your objects. Example: `FROM SecondDatabase.dbo.SomeTable`, this would then always execute on the `SomeTable` table defined for the `dbo` owner on the `SecondDatabase` database schema even if the current context was a different user and different database schema. If you do not qualify those 2 items (database schema and schema owner) then the current active values are used for both of those implicitly. In the case above if you executed a stored proc defined in the database `Main` with schema user `dbo` then it would be `main.dbo.SomeTable`

Comment: Totally not getting what you are asking. I assume you mean something like select * from SecondDatabase.dbo.TableName where somevalue = 'asdf'. But I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: The (now edited) query above will always execute on `SecondDatabase.dbo.SomeTable` even if the active database context was another database and even if the active user had a different default schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use FirstDatabase
select name 
from SecondDatabase.dbo.SomeTable 
where id = 56
```

Question:

> will it run in the main database and go all the way to the second
>   database and returns the data, or will it run in the second database
>   and you have the select result directly?

Your first assumption is correct:

**This query will run in a first database**, it will use context and all settings (ANSI, query optimizer and statistic related) of the first database but will get data from a table of the second database.

Just an example from a life: if database have to stay in an old compatibility mode, but new T-SQL features need occasionally to be used, query can switch context to tempdb (which normally set to the latest compatibility level) and run queries referencing data from any other database where access is granted. Usage of those new features will not raise exception

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the difference between a Database and an Instance.

An instance is the software running the SQL service. Each instance can have multiple databases. For example, there is a `master` database and a `tempdb` database for each instance of SQL Server, these are system databases. You can create any number of user databases. All these databases will be handled by the same SQL Server instance (on the same machine).

A particular client session is connected first to an instance and then to a particular database, thats why you include which database you will connect to by default on connection strings (or by login). When you write `select name from SecondDatabase.dbo.SomeTable`, you are telling the SQL service to retrieve data from the `SecondDatabase`, even if your session is linked to any other database. The engine will then use your login credential to match a user of the other database (since users go by database and logins by instance) to validate if it has enough privileges to query that table, before searching for the data.

A complete different story would be trying to access data from another instance (machine), in which you will need a linked server, a openrowset or such.

Answer (score 0):

The (now edited) query above will always execute on `SecondDatabase.dbo.SomeTable` even if the active database context was another database and even if the active user had a different default schema. This is because the object `SomeTable` is qualified with the schema and the schema owner.

Test to illustrate that the following still returns the executed results (*assuming the objects exist and the active user context has access to them*)

```
USE [OtherDatabaseSchema]
GO

SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM [SecondDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTable]
```